# How do I use different versions of an icon from same PNG file?

Tags: icons

I've seen in many websites, that they store multiple versions of an image, whether it is an icon, or a button, or anything else, in the same PNG file. I even stumbled upon a PNG, where there were 24 different versions of the image, which was used in a keyframe animation. How do I achieve this? Currently, I save all the versions of a single image in different files.

Comment: Should be moved to graphic design.

Comment: I'm fairly new to the community, and not being so well-versed with the rules, posted my question where it seemed to fit. Is there any way I can shift this question to another category? Or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are CSS sprites for that. CSS Sprites are a means of combining multiple images into a single image file for use on a website, to help with performance.

More information: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/